# Encode DVD to H.264

Tags: ubuntu, dvd, encoding, h.264

I generally use dvd::rip software to encode DVDs to XviD files with specified size. I try the options of the software to encode to H.264, but it wasn's successful.

How can I rip DVDs and encode to H.264 ? 
(with dvd::rip, or other software)

OS : Ubuntu 10.10 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the best graphical video encoding software I have come across is [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) which is open source and available on pretty much every platform.

If you're not too worried about a fancy graphical interface you probably want ffmpeg or mencoder as they're fast and light.

Comment: There's no problem with command line tools, dvd::rip use them too. I just not learn the parameters what can create a fixed size video with 2 pass encoding with mencoder